# Set LDAP Path to login with Active directory in Kentico 9

Tags: active-directory, kentico

I have one credentials which i have to set it as LDAP Path.

URL:     https:\172.23.150.152/exchange

Server:  172.23.150.152

Port     25

Domain – QTLYRSLT

When i am using this url in browser so it's asking for user id and password.
I provide my userid and password so it's opened one microsoft outlook web access with my name.

so this credentials need to set as LDAP path.

but this provided domain name does not have .com or something postfix so here i am stuck.

But when i tried to import users from this path in Kentico Import Utility so there i used only this ip address: 172.23.150.152 and my user id and password so i am able to import all the users in Kentico. It means this credentials is working fine.

Please help me here to set exact path for LDAP.

Answer (score 2):

The instructions are here: https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Configuring+mixed-mode+authentication

The path should look something like LDAP://mydomain.example.com/DC=mydomain,DC=example,DC=com

I believe active directory, although the server may not have a 'domain' per say, still has the DC names that define the directory.  You can still use the IP to reference, although i would probably set a host file so you can have a domain pointing to it.

LDAP://172.23.150.152/DC=mydomain,DC=example,DC=com

Comment: Hi Trevor, Thanks for your suggestion. My question here is what is example and com?

Comment: This i have not mentioned in my question. i have changed something in LDAP Path and now the new error is "Unable to established secure connection".